# Azure Open AI add your own data, 'Unrecognized request argument supplied: dataSources', 'type': 'invalid_request_error'

Tags: python, openai-api, azure-cognitive-search, azure-openai

I am trying to replicate the the add your own data feature for Azure Open AI following the instruction found here: [Quickstart: Chat with Azure OpenAI models using your own data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/ai-services/openai/use-your-data-quickstart?tabs=command-line%2Cpython-new&pivots=programming-language-python)

```
import os
import openai
import dotenv

dotenv.load_dotenv()

endpoint = os.environ.get("AOAIEndpoint")
api_key = os.environ.get("AOAIKey")
deployment = "gpt-4-32k"

client = openai.AzureOpenAI(
    # base_url=f"{endpoint}/openai/deployments/{deployment}/extensions",
    azure_endpoint=endpoint,
    api_key=api_key,
    api_version="2023-08-01-preview",
)

completion = client.chat.completions.create(
    model=deployment,
    messages=[
        {
            "role": "user",
            "content": "My user query",
        },
    ],
    extra_body={
        "dataSources": [
            {
                "type": "AzureCognitiveSearch",
                "parameters": {
                    "endpoint": os.environ["SearchEndpoint"],
                    "key": os.environ["SearchKey"],
                    "indexName": os.environ["SearchIndex"]
                }
            }
        ]
    }
)

print(f"{completion.choices[0].message.role}: {completion.choices[0].message.content}")
```

However, I was not able to use the 'dataSources' parameter in the API call. I would get the following error: `BadRequestError: Error code: 400 - {'error': {'message': 'Unrecognized request argument supplied: dataSources', 'type': 'invalid_request_error', 'param': None, 'code': None}}`. If I were to use the `base_url` like the example, I would get an error: `InternalServerError: upstream request timeout`. Running the code with without the `extra_body` parameter would work just fine.

I am currently using the newest `openai` python library. I have also tried the example with `openai==0.28.1` and I got the error: `InvalidRequestError: Unrecognized request argument supplied: dataSources`.

I have look into the official github for [OpenAI Python API library](https://github.com/openai/openai-python) and it is not clear how I should implement the add your own data feature.

Answer (score 1):

For this to work, I had to use openai v 0.28.1. I used here the index named "my-precreated-index", which was created based on fake documents describing Contoso corporation (created by Microsoft for their demo projects). And I was able to ask questions and receive answers related to Contoso, via API calls to gpt-3.5-turbo model deployed previously to openai resource.
The trick was to use openai.api_version = "2023-06-01-preview" (other versions might work too), and openai 0.28.1 python module (the latest version give me the same error about dataSources).
Here is a code that worked for me:

```
# Via https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/ai-services/openai/use-your-data-quickstart?tabs=command-line%2Cpython&pivots=programming-language-python
# Using openai ver 0.28.1 (older version, not new 1.6+)
# Also for Search API, need to use Primary Admin key (not my own query key), otherwise can't authenticate to send a search call

import os
import openai
import requests

openai.api_base = "https://my_openai_service.openai.azure.com/" 

# Azure OpenAI on your own data is only supported by the 2023-08-01-preview API version ? No, 2023-06-01 works too
openai.api_version = "2023-06-01-preview"
openai.api_type = 'azure'
openai.api_key = 'aaaaaaaaaa' 

def setup_byod(deployment_id: str) -> None:

    class BringYourOwnDataAdapter(requests.adapters.HTTPAdapter):

     def send(self, request, **kwargs):
         request.url = f"{openai.api_base}/openai/deployments/{deployment_id}/extensions/chat/completions?api-version={openai.api_version}"
         return super().send(request, **kwargs)

    session = requests.Session()

    # Mount a custom adapter which will use the extensions endpoint for any call using the given `deployment_id`
    session.mount(
        prefix=f"{openai.api_base}/openai/deployments/{deployment_id}",
        adapter=BringYourOwnDataAdapter()
    )

    openai.requestssession = session

aoai_deployment_id = "gpt-35-turbo" 
setup_byod(aoai_deployment_id)

my_question= "What is the goal of Contoso?" #"When Contoso corp was created?" #"When Contoso was created?" # "What is Contoso corporation?",
completion = openai.ChatCompletion.create(
    messages=[
                {
                "role": "user", 
                "content": my_question,
                }
            ],
    deployment_id="gpt-35-turbo", 
    dataSources=[  # camelCase is intentional, as this is the format the API expects
        {
            "type": "AzureCognitiveSearch",
            "parameters": {
                "endpoint": "https://my_search_service.search.windows.net",
                "key": "Need_search_admin_key_here",
                "indexName": "my-precreated-index",
            }
        }
    ]
)

print(f"Question: {my_question}")
print(f"Text part of the response:\n{completion.choices[0].messages[1].content}\n")
print("-"*50)
print(f"Context part of the response:\n{completion.choices[0].messages[0].content}\n")
print("-"*50)
print(completion)
```

Here are examples:
**Question**: When Contoso corp was created?
Text part of the response: The retrieved documents do not provide information on when Contoso Corporation was created. The requested information is not available in the retrieved data. Please try another query or topic.
**Question**: Bwo is the owner of Contoso?
Text part of the response: The retrieved documents do not provide information about who the owner of Contoso is. Please try another query or topic.
**Question**: What is the goal of Contoso?
Text part of the response: The retrieved documents do not provide enough information to determine the specific goal of Contoso. However, the documents do mention some of Contoso's business needs, such as adhering to regional regulatory requirements, improving vendor and partner management, improving mobile workforce productivity and device management, reducing remote access infrastructure, and scaling down on-premises datacenters [doc1].

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned, you are using `openai==0.28.1` but the provided code is for [OpenAI Python 1.x](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/ai-services/openai/use-your-data-quickstart?tabs=command-line%2Cpython-new&pivots=programming-language-python#tabpanel_1_python-new).

To fix this you can either install the `opanai 1.x package`.
[image]

Or you can check the below sample code for openai 0.28.1 which uses `request package` for the task:

```py
import os
import openai
import dotenv
import requests

dotenv.load_dotenv()

openai.api_base = os.environ.get("AOAIEndpoint")

openai.api_version = ""
openai.api_type = 'azure'
openai.api_key = os.environ.get("AOAIKey")

def setup_byod(deployment_id: str) -> None:

    class BringYourOwnDataAdapter(requests.adapters.HTTPAdapter):

     def send(self, request, **kwargs):
         request.url = f"{openai.api_base}/openai/deployments/{deployment_id}/extensions/chat/completions?api-version={openai.api_version}"
         return super().send(request, **kwargs)

    session = requests.Session()

    
    session.mount(
        prefix=f"{openai.api_base}/openai/deployments/{deployment_id}",
        adapter=BringYourOwnDataAdapter()
    )

    openai.requestssession = session

aoai_deployment_id = os.environ.get("AOAIDeploymentId")
setup_byod(aoai_deployment_id)

completion = openai.ChatCompletion.create(
    messages=[{"role": "user", "content": ""}],
    deployment_id=os.environ.get("AOAIDeploymentId"),
    dataSources=[ 
        {
            "type": "AzureCognitiveSearch",
            "parameters": {
                "endpoint": os.environ.get("SearchEndpoint"),
                "key": os.environ.get("SearchKey"),
                "indexName": os.environ.get("SearchIndex"),
            }
        }
    ]
)
print(completion)
```

Comment: Hi thank you for replying. But I am currently on openai version 1.3.5. I have tried the code example with openai version 0.28.1 and it still has the same issue.

Comment: Have you tried your code with openai version 1.3.5?

Answer (score 0):

I think it should work if you create your client with the `base_url` argument instead of `azure_endpoint`:

```
client = openai.AzureOpenAI(
    base_url=f"{endpoint}/openai/deployments/{deployment}/extensions",
```